# pacemaker hangs while stopping

Tags: linux, cluster, pacemaker

I have recently installed pacemaker and corosync for managin a virtual IP.

The thing is that when I want to stop a resource (Virtual IP) on all the nodes, the stop command hangs.

```
[root@isis ~]# sudo pcs cluster stop --all
isis: Stopping Cluster...
```

My configuration is:

```
[root@isis ~]# sudo pcs status
Cluster name: cluster-osiris
Last updated: Mon Dec  8 00:09:29 2014
Last change: Mon Dec  8 00:09:24 2014 via cibadmin on isis
Stack: corosync
Current DC: horus (2) - partition with quorum
Version: 1.1.10-32.el7_0.1-368c726
2 Nodes configured
2 Resources configured


Online: [ horus isis ]

Full list of resources:

 HAproxy        (systemd:haproxy):      Started horus
 ClusterIP-01   (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started isis

PCSD Status:
  isis: Online
  horus: Online

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

If i stop cluster node by node, it works well:

```
[root@isis ~]# sudo pcs cluster stop horus
horus: Stopping Cluster...
[root@isis ~]# sudo pcs cluster stop isis
isis: Stopping Cluster...
[root@isis ~]# sudo pcs status 
Error: cluster is not currently running on this node
```

Please, Could you help me with this issue?

Tks!

Comment: I have activated stonith and I dont have the problem any more. It's ok this configuration for a two node active/passive cluster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is to just stop the resource from running on any nodes in a cluster then you'd want to disable that resource using:

`pcs resource disable ClusterIP-01`

Your command `sudo pcs cluster stop --all` would be shutting down the cluster itself (and any resources controlled by that cluster).

[Managing Cluster Resources](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Configuring_the_Red_Hat_High_Availability_Add-On_with_Pacemaker/s1-resource_control-HAAR.html)